# What would be the consequences of a preferred reference frame?

Tags: special-relativity, inertial-frames, noethers-theorem, aether

As I understand it, the conservation law associated with frame invariance via Noether's theorem is just the constancy of the center of mass at $t=0$, which is rather obvious, and therefore somewhat useless and uninteresting as conservation laws go.

However, that suggests to me that, if we were to discover evidence of a preferred frame, thus breaking frame invariance symmetry, that that alone, regardless of the details of how this preferred frame is realized, would imply that the center of mass at $t=0$ somehow need not be constant. Which seems absurd. So, what does that actually mean? Would there be any significant consequences of a preferred frame, simply by virtue of such a thing existing?

Comment: Special relativity has an interpretation with a preferred frame (Lorentz's ether), and FLRW universes in general relativity have a [preferred comoving frame](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comoving_distance), ours is one of them. So it won't amount to much, perhaps existence of some favorably placed observers for whom the observed picture simplifies, if that.